# Why are ADF datasets important?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

In Azure Data Factory v2 I've created a number of pipelines. I noticed that each pipeline I create there is a source and destination dataset created.

According to the ADF documentation: ***A dataset is a named view of data that simply points or references the data you want to use in your activities as inputs and outputs.***

These datasets are visible within my data factory. I'm curious why I would care about these? These almost seem like 'under the hood' objects ADF creates to move data around. What value are these to me and why would I care about them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These datasets are entities that can be reused. For example, dataset A can be referenced by many pipelines if those pipelines need the same data (same table or same file).
Linked services can be reused too. I think that's why ADF has these concepts.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question. I know what they are used for. My question was, "why should I care about these?" Why do I need to even see them?

Comment: Put it this way - you are creating a dataset that links to a source table that can be used in various pipelines to move the data to targets like Data Lake, Data Warehouse, etc. Using datasets, you do not need to create a link to the table (that will contain schema to the table) again for each pipeline. That is the reason you need them. Other reason is you do not need to specify file formats for files in each task that is trying to consume or output the file in data lake. Specify in the dataset and use it. That is why you need to define them and take care of them.

Comment: I do see issue with data factory creating hundreds of datasets while selecting multiple tables - making them hard to manage. You should try to make them configurable using parameters, so you have limited number of manageable and useful datasets.

Comment: That’s the behavior of v1 and previous behavior of v2 copy data tool. Currently, it will only generate two datasets even for multiple tables.

Comment: Fang - that is right. It just changed few days back and was much needed. Thanks for pointing that out. We have been avoiding using copy wizard, for this very reason.

Comment: Thanks for letting us know. Didn’t realize that this question is related copy wizard.

Answer (score 0):

You may be seeing those show up in your Factory if you create pipelines via the Copy Wizard Tool. That will create Datasets for your Source & Sink. The Copy Activity is the primary consumer of Datasets in ADF Pipelines.

Comment: You should add this as a comment and not an answer. The StackOverflow police are going to ruthlessly downvote this. I would delete this answer and add as a comment. The answer though is, I'm doing both.

Comment: Good advice. I changed my answer to an actual answer :)

Comment: This doesn't answer my question though. I want to know why I should care about these datasets. What value are they to me?

Comment: Datasets are used by the source and sink to define the shape and attributes of the data that you are copying or accessing.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ADFv2 to transform data, no DataSet is required. But if you are using ADF copy activity to copy data, DataSet is used to let ADF know the path and name of object to copy from/to.  Once you have one dataset created, it can be used in many pipelines. Could you please help to let me understand more why creating a dataset is a friction to you in your projects?

Comment: They are not "a friction" to me. My question was, "why should I care about them?". Why does Microsoft think I need to see these?